# how to make sure image shows over my twitter bootstrap 3 input field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a jquery plugin to help with scrolling to the bottom and the top on my page http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-For-Smooth-Scroll-To-Top-Bottom-scrollToTop.html.

The problem I have is that the images for the plugin do not show over my twitter bootstrap 3 input fields...

[image]

The css for the plugin is fairly short and simple so I'll paste it below. How can I modify it to make sure the images appear on top of the input field?

thanks

```
#totopscroller {
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 43px;
}
#totopscroller div {
    width: 49px;
    height: 43px;
    position: relative;
}
#totopscroller a {
    display: none;
    background: url('totopicons.png');
    width: 49px;
    height: 43px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: medium none;
    margin: 0 0 -1px;
    border: 1px solid #949494;
}
.totopscroller-top {
    background-position: 0 0 !important;
}
.totopscroller-lnk {
    background-position: 0 -43px !important;
}
.totopscroller-prev {
    background-position: 0 -129px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.totopscroller-bottom {
    background-position: 0 -86px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

```
.element{
  z-index:22;
}
```